# I ran as fast as I could have?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence of mine, please:

*1) I will run as fast as I **can**.*

The past tense version of 1) would be:

*2) I ran as fast as I **could**.*

---

Can we use "**could have**" in place of "**could**" in 2)?

*3) I ran as fast as I **could have**.*

What is the difference between *could* and *could have*?

Comment: It would not be good because you have already used the 'run' verb. There is no need to repeat it, we still remember the topic of the sentence. Even if you are comparing yourself with someone else, there is no need: "I will run as fast as Ali [can]."

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between "*I ran as fast as I could*" and "*I ran as fast as I could have*"?

Comment: @Mr.X I edited your question to remove the use of the second *run* that was distracting from what you were really asking. (I don't personally have a good immediate answer to the question. The two mean essentially the same thing, and there's nothing wrong with *could have*, but it's not normally used that way. It looks slightly odd to me—but only slightly.)